# Retrieve posts created by a specific Symfony user

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a $ type boolean property, I need to differentiate my two types of posts I am trying to retrieve posts of type = true, (which are recipes) of a specific user for the user profile page.

```
/**
     * @Route("/profil/{id}", name="profil", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * 
     */
    public function index(User $user): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $publications = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(
            array('users' => $user->getId()),
            array('created_at' => 'Desc')
        );

         ****// list the publication of recipes
         $recette = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(['type'=>true],['created_at' => 'desc']);****
        

        // recuperar las 3 ultimas recetas para el sidebar rigth
        $lastRecettes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)->lastXRecette(4);
        // lister les 9 dernières recettes
        $recette = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)->lastPRecette(9);      

        return $this->render('profil/index.html.twig', [          
            'publications' => $publications,
            'recettes' => $recette,
            'user' => $user,
            'lastRecettes' => $lastRecettes,
        ]);
    }
```

the highlighted part allows me to retrieve all the recipes but I don't know how to add the user I tried this but it is not correct:

```
$recette = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(['type'=>true], ['users' => $user->getId()],['created_at' => 'desc']);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I well understood your problem

But may your code should look like this :

```
/**
     * @Route("/profil/{id}", name="profil", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * 
     */
    public function index(User $user): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // First type
        $truePublications = $em->getRepository(Publication::class)->findBy(
            array('user' => $user->getId(), 'type' => true),
            array('created_at' => 'DESC'),
        );

        // Second type
        $falsePublications = $em->getRepository(Publication::class)->findBy(
            array('user' => $user->getId(), 'type' => false),
            array('created_at' => 'DESC'),
        );

        // recuperar las 3 ultimas recetas para el sidebar rigth
        $lastRecettes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)->lastXRecette(3);
        
        // lister les 9 dernières recettes
        $recette = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)->lastPRecette(9);      

        return $this->render('profil/index.html.twig', [          
            'trueTypePublications' => $truePublications,
            'falseTypePublications' => $falsePublications,
            'recettes' => $recette,
            'user' => $user,
            'lastRecettes' => $lastRecettes,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to do it and it has not worked either, I have this error , " ORMException::unrecognizedField('user') ". thank you

Comment: I have fixed the error but; still not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as proposed (but maybe in a confused way) by @mustapha-ghlissi you have to include the test on your user on the first argument of the `findBy` method like this :

```
$recette = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(['type' => true, 'users' => $user->getId()],['created_at' => 'desc']);
```

Comment: your logic is good, but it doesn't work for me, i dont know why?. thank you

Comment: Could you provide your « Publication » entity code ?

Comment: you were right, your answer is correct, thank you so much

Comment: you were right, your answer is correct, but it works in the publicationManager.php file and not directly in the controller i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

PublicationRepository.php

```
     public function getRecettesUser(User $user)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->andWhere('p.users = :user')
            ->andWhere('p.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->setParameter('type', true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

create a folder src/Manager/PublicationManager.php

```
use App\Entity\Publication;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class PublicationManager
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

       
    public function getRecetteByUser(User $user)
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository(Publication::class)->findBy(
         ['type' => true, 'users' => $user->getId()],['created_at' => 'desc']
         );        
    }

}
```

My Controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("/profil/{id}", name="profil", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * 
     */
    public function index(User $user, PublicationManager $publicationManager): Response
    {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $publications = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(
            array('users' => $user->getId()),
            array('created_at' => 'Desc')
        );

         // recuperer les 3 dernier recettes pour le sidebar right
        $lastRecettes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)
        ->lastXRecette(4);
       
        return $this->render('profil/index.html.twig', [
            'publications' => $publications,
            'recettes' => $publicationManager->getRecetteByUser($user),         
            'lastRecettes' => $lastRecettes,
             
        ]);
     }
```